# ruby dynamic hash keys

Tags: ruby, json, hash, amazon-s3

I have a list of paths of s3 files form a bucket like

```
a/b/c
a/b/c/d.txt
a/d/e.txt
```

Is there a way I can create a json representation of the above info, I'm looking for something like

`{:a=>{:b=>{:c=>[d.txt]},:d=>[e.txt]}}`

I have generated the dynamic key names using eval but I'm not able to do

`eval(a[:b]X) where X is something like [:c]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have array of strings, each string mean path to file?

Comment: it could point to a folder or to a file

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you're asking for. A method to convert a list of strings into this hash object? A method to generate this hash object, given an S3 bucket? A class defining methods for displaying/adding to/removing from the list of file names? And, why are you converting folders to symbols; I think they would be better left as strings.

Comment: I'm trying to display the bucket contents in a tree view using js tree so I need to convert the info to the json supported by js tree

Comment: @Subash how do you know if it is a directory or a file?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm a little unclear on what should happen if there are files as well as folders in a folder, though. What is the desired result for the list `['a/b.txt', 'a/c/d.txt']`? My first guess would be `{:a => ['b.txt', {:c => ['d.txt']}]}`, is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
files = %w(a/b/c.txt a/b/c/d.txt a/d/e.txt)
files.reject do |f| # first of all, remove redundant dirs
  files.any? { |ff| ff != f && ff.start_with?(f) }
end.each_with_object({}) do |f, memo|
  *path, file = f.split('/')
  bucket = path.inject(memo) { |acc, k| acc[k] ||= {} }
  (bucket[:files] ||= []) << file
end
#⇒ {
#  "a" => {
#    "b" => {
#         "c" => {
#        :files => [
#          [0] "d.txt"
#        ]
#      },
#      :files => [
#        [0] "c.txt"
#      ]
#    },
#    "d" => {
#      :files => [
#        [0] "e.txt"
#      ]
#    }
#  }
# }
```